# Genesis - Adding custom hooks to display secondary navigation

Tags: templates, hooks

within my functions.php I added the following piece of code to display my footer accordingly:

```
//* Customize the entire footer
remove_action( 'genesis_footer', 'genesis_do_footer' );
add_action( 'genesis_footer', 'my_custom_footer' );
function my_custom_footer() {

    ?>
    <div class="site-footer-logo">
        <img src="<?=get_stylesheet_directory_uri();?>/images/my-logo-small.png" alt="My Logo Small" />
    </div>
    <p>Copyright &copy; <?=date('Y');?>, my-url.com.</p>
    <?php
}
```

I want to have the secondary navigation menu displayed between the div `.site-footer-logo` and the following paragraph. Can i just add something like `do_action('my_own_hook');` and then access it via `add_action( 'my_own_hook', 'genesis_do_subnav' );` ?

Is this 'allowed' in the Genesis world?

Thanks.

Comment: This should help: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/97599/21376  I am not sure if the question is a duplicate but it is pretty close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. you can do that.

```
function my_custom_footer() {
    ?>
    <div class="site-footer-logo">
        <img src="<?=get_stylesheet_directory_uri();?>/images/my-logo-small.png" alt="My Logo Small" />
    </div>
    <?php do_action('my_own_hook'); ?>
    <p>Copyright &copy; <?=date('Y');?>, my-url.com.</p>
    <?php
}

add_action( 'my_own_hook', 'genesis_do_subnav' );

function genesis_do_subnav(){
    wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'secondary-menu' ) );
}
```

You also can directly add:

```
</div>
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'secondary-menu' ) ); ?>
<p>
```

Note that `secondary-menu` here should be [registered](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menus).