# how to enqueque code in a php file from functions.php

Tags: php, functions

Im building a website with wordpress, using a child theme.
there is a file in the main theme folders, called entry.php
that is where I need to add a bit of php at the *bottom* of this document.

I don't want to touch the parent theme files, to avoid problems when I update the theme.

**How can I embed/insert PHP code in that specific file/ part of the code?**

Is this done using filters? embed? can you please guide me I have been searching in google but I dont know if im using the right keywords to search.

Im learning php and this would be of great help :)

Further details:

Ideally I want this bit of code to be embedded right before the end of the  "/section"

```
<?php if (in_category('3')) { ?>

<div class="recommended-bottom">

    <h3 class="recommended-title">WRITING</h3>
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[pt_view id="343aa4f4c3"]');?>
        </div>

<?php }else { ?>
<?php } ?>
```

The code in entry.php is:

```
<article <?php post_class(); if( ! is_single() ) echo ' itemprop="blogPost"'; ?> itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">

    <?php shiroi_get_post_view( 'parts/header', get_post_format() ); ?>
    <?php shiroi_get_post_view( 'media/media', get_post_format() ); ?>

    <section class="entry-content post-content" itemprop="articleBody">

        <?php do_action( 'shiroi_before_post_body_content' );

        if( is_single() || 'the_content' === shiroi_get_option( 'blog_summary' ) ) : 
            the_content( __( 'Continue Reading', 'shiroi' ) );
        else:
            the_excerpt();
            printf( '<div class="more-link-wrap"><a href="%s" class="more-link">%s</a></div>', esc_url( get_permalink() ), esc_html__( 'Continue Reading', 'shiroi' ) );
        endif;

        if( is_single() ):
            if( get_the_tags() && shiroi_get_option( 'blog_show_tags' ) ):

            ?><p class="post-tags">
                <?php the_tags( '<i class="fa fa-tags"></i>', ', ' ); ?>
            </p>
            <?php endif;

            wp_link_pages(array(
                'before' => '<nav class="entries-page-nav"><ul>', 
                'after' => '</ul></nav>', 
                'separator' => '', 
                'pagelink' => '<span class="entries-page-nav-item">%</span>'
            ));
        endif;

        do_action( 'shiroi_after_post_body_content' ); ?>




    </section>

    <?php if( is_single() ) : 
        shiroi_get_post_view( 'parts/footer', get_post_format() );
        shiroi_get_post_view( 'parts/comments', get_post_format() );
    endif; ?>


</article>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is the sum of the code for that file then the only place near the bottom is that `do_action`-- `do_action( 'shiroi_after_post_body_content' );`-- which looks to be what you want.

```
function test_new_action() {
  echo 'Howdy';
}
add_action('shiroi_after_post_body_content','test_new_action');
```

Depending upon how this file is included there might be other hooks.

You can't add code to the file otherwise without editing it manually or [with PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

For reference (maybe helpful): https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/97599/21376

Comment: THANKS this was very helpful. I have learned a lot today. I will continue using Hooks and replace my previous dirty "theme hacks..."